# MongoDB/PHP unset an array by key

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a document that has a nested array.  I want to delete an item in the array by it's key value.  I've tried doing an update with:

`array('$unset' => array('item.key' => 1))`

`array('$pull' => array('item.key' => 1))`

Doing, `$unset` , kept the key but nulled out the value, I want to get rid of it entirely.  Pull didn't do anything.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: It nulls for a good reason, mainly due to performing other operations on that array as well and the indexes getting messed up etc, unfortunately you will need to do this client side unless you account for nulls in your code or do two queries, one to null and the other to remove those nulls

Comment: Works for me, thanks! Can you answer this and I'll select you?

Comment: Actually Asyas might be better. I didn't think of using $pull like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `$pull` you have to specify the entire array element you want to delete, luckily `$pull` is special in that you can specify a match criteria for the element you are `$pull`ing

Here is an example:

```
db.array.update({},{$pull:{a:{"key2":{$exists:true}}}},{multi:true})
```

This will delete array element where "key2" exists as a keyname regardless of the value.
Sounds like this is what you want.

Here is a [reference](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull).